# Is it normal for react to re-render component when using promise inside a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm in progress learning react and I have created an app with a login form. When the login form is submitted the login function passed to the component is executing twice as indicated in the console (logInUser – "running") even though the login button is only clicked once.

The function (loginUser) contains a promise blogService.setToken(xyz).then(xyz) and when the promise is removed the function only executes once.

While I have a method called setToken, this is not using a react state and so this shouldn't be contributing to the issue. I'm wondering why this the promise causing the component to re-render and if anyone could point me into the direction of documentation if promises cause a re-render. I can't seem to hit the right keywords to find the answer.

Can create a GitHub repo to share if that helps. Code below.

Cheers.

Console log

```
[Log] handleSubmit – "running"
[Log] handleSubmit – {token: "xxx", username: "xxx", name: "xxx"} 
[Log] logInUser – "running"
[Log] logInUser: returnedObject – {token: "xxx", username: "xxx", name: "xxx"}
[Log] logInUser – "running"
```

App.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import blogService from "./services/blogs";
import LoginForm from "./components/Login";

//...

const App = () => {
 const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

 const logInUser = (returnedObj) => {
    console.log("logInUser", "running");
    if (returnedObj) {
      console.log("logInUser: returnedObject", returnedObj);

      // Causing a rerender
      blogService.setToken(returnedObj.token)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('hello')
        // then go and set the user
      });

    }

  };

//...

  return (
    <div>
      {user === null ? (
        <div>
          <h1>Login</h1>
          <Notification message={notificationMessage} />
          <LoginForm loggedInUser={logInUser} />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h1>Logged in</h1>
        </div>
  )
```

components/Login.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import loginService from "../services/login";

const LoginForm = ({ loggedInUser }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.clear();

    const user = await loginService
      .login({
        username,
        password,
      })
      .then((returnedUser) => {
        console.log("handleSubmit", "running");
        console.log("handleSubmit", returnedUser);
        setUsername("");
        setPassword("");
        loggedInUser(returnedUser);
      })
      .catch(() => loggedInUser(null));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="Username"
          value={username}
          onChange={({ target }) => setUsername(target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="Password"
          value={password}
          onChange={({ target }) => setPassword(target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

services/login.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
const baseUrl = '/api/login'

const login = async credentials => {
    const response = await axios.post(baseUrl, credentials)
    return response.data
}

export default { login }
```

service/blog.js

```
let token = null;

const setToken = (newToken) => {
  token = `bearer ${newToken}`;
};
export default { setToken };
```

Comment: You're calling both `setUsername` and `setPassword` which both cause a rerender (probably batched by react). Also `[Log] logInUser – "running"` isn't an indication of a render, but of the function being called.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if this hits the mark. 
setUsername + setPassword do cause a re-render of the input fields but not when handleSubmit is called. logInUser is passed as prop and then called when handleSubmit is called. I expect logInUser to be called once (or as I've described 'running') on handleSubmit but it then gets called a second time without any interaction from the user which is what I don't understand. 
Thanks for your reply.